# How did militia barracks look in the 19th century?

Tags: military, 19th-century

I’m seeking some information (preferably **photos** or **art**, but **description** would also help a bit) on how **the exterior of militia barracks** looked in **~1790 - 1870** in Europe.

It would be helpful to mention in which country the barracks in each image was located.

---

I was able to find this image only, but I need more images with greater detail. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Preston Barracks, 1850]

Preston Barracks, UK (1850) from [mybrightonandhove.com](http://www.mybrightonandhove.org.uk/page_id__6198_path__0p115p210p690p.aspx).

Comment: Does your search explicitly concern **milita** barracks **specifically**, or military barracks in general?

Comment: If the question concerns military barracks in general, just a note: Wikimedia Commons has a [great plenty of images](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Barracks_by_country) sorted by country. Sadly, they usually aren't categorized by chronology, only by location.

Comment: @tohuwawohu - I'm looking for image of **any** exterior of militiary barracks in the 19th century. The images will be used as reference images. Wikimedia gallery of barracks is awesome!

Comment: Intersecting the "Barracks" category of Wikimedia Commons with all images under Public Domain (Category: PD Old) gives a quite useful search result of **"older" images**,  removing modern (copyright-protected) ones: http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php?language=commons&project=wikimedia&categories=Barracks%7C5%0D%0APD+Old&ns%5B6%5D=1&ext_image_data=1&file_usage_data=1&interface_language=en (click on "Do it" button at the bottom of search form)

Comment: Faster search with the "quick intersection" utility: http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/quick_intersection.php?lang=commons&project=wikimedia&cats=Barracks%0D%0APD+Old&ns=6&depth=4&max=30000&start=0&format=html&redirects=&callback=&norun

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There wasn't really any standardised design, as you can see from the variations in the images already shown.

This is in part because many barracks would be just repurposed other buildings, and of course building styles would vary over time and space as well.

You'd get to see thus the same variety as in any other type of building, but likely with a tendency towards larger blocky buildings, easily divided into similar sized rooms for use as quarters and offices, armouries and mess halls.

http://www.legerplaats.nl/breda/_breda.htm shows a Dutch barracks built in 1764, expanded in 1878, and still in use today (plus several others from the same era, including interior photographs).
[image]
[image]
[image]

Last image looks like a messhall, the furniture would of course have been different in the period you're after, but the layout shows clearly.